# Aborted (core dumped) in PQconnectdb C++ Codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, postgresql-9.3

I have code like these for my codeblocks plugin:

```
 conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=codeblocks user=postgres password=postgres host=127.0.0.1 port=5432");

if(PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK) {
    wxMessageBox(_("Database connection failed!" ));
    PQfinish(conn);
    return 0;
}
```

On that the connection to database will error since it does not exists and the "Database connection failed!" message will show up.
My problem is, it close the Codeblocks IDE and shows an error in my terminal like these:

```
Exception: Unknown exception was raised. The application will terminate immediately...
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How could i catch the error on PQconnectdb so that it will no close my IDE? BTW, im in Ubuntu 14.04 and using C++.

Comment: Aren't you use try...catch?

Comment: As suggest, use block try-catch. Moreover, check if you have installed one or more version of Codeblocks.

Comment: to be honest, i dont know actually what to catch. :(
i just followed this sample in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-example.html

Answer (score 0):

First you can include your indicted code in try-catch:

```
try{
  conn = PQconnectdb("dbname=codeblocks user=postgres password=postgres host=127.0.0.1 port=5432");

  if(PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK) {
    wxMessageBox(_("Database connection failed!" ));
    PQfinish(conn);
    return 0;
  }
} catch (...) {
  /* add breakpoint here */
}
```

Moreover, you can check if you have installed more of one version of Codeblocks.

- DB exist?
- Is postgresql installed?
- Are you using right host and/or port?